# mvc @Url.Action to new area doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, area

I have the tag img that its src is with Url.Action to function in the controller inside Area.
My code :
the view is in folder Start in the area Login

```
  <img id="CaptchaImg" src='@Url.Action("ShowCaptchaImage", "start", new { area = "Login" })' />
```

the function in the controller Start in the area Login:

```
    public CaptchaImageResult ShowCaptchaImage()
     {
         return new CaptchaImageResult();
     }
```

in the browser I see that the src is not inside the area.
what Did I do wrong?

UPDATE:
in the debug I see that I come to the function ShowCaptchaImage. but I don't see the picture in the browser

Comment: May be typo The controller is 'Start' , in url.action 'Strat'

Comment: It wasn't my problem

Comment: Is `CaptchaImageResult` a string? You're putting this back into the `src` attribute of the `img` tag so you need it to be a URL string to the image resource. Also `start` in this case would be referring to a controller, not a folder.

Comment: `return new CaptchaImageResult()` should return string of image URL here. Or you can return `ContentResult` to create `img` tag at view page after action method selected image to display.